# How the ipython kernel process is killed?

Tags: python, ipython

Try to understand how the ipython kernel manager kills a kernel process.

I am looking into the [multikernelmanager.py](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/blob/master/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py) that implements a kernel manager for multiple kernels. I want to understand how a kernel process is actually killed. But in the code, it just removes the reference of a kernel process from a dictionary. How could that be sufficient to terminate a process?

```
@kernel_method
def remove_kernel(self, kernel_id):
    """remove a kernel from our mapping.
    Mainly so that a kernel can be removed if it is already dead,
    without having to call shutdown_kernel.
    The kernel object is returned.
    """
    return self._kernels.pop(kernel_id)
```

Comment: Maybe check out `shutdown_kernel`, referenced in that docstring.

Comment: The shutdown_kernel just calls the remove_kernel method with no additional logic.

Comment: I just had a quick look - the magic is in the decorator. It calls the method with the same name on the specifical kernel before running the contents of the actual function. You can see how it does that up the top of the file.

Comment: I see. Did not realize the decorator. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No problem. I've added that response as an answer - feel free to upvote and accept if you consider your question resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

The magic is in the `@kernel_method` decorator, as defined at the top of the file.

```
def kernel_method(f):
    """decorator for proxying MKM.method(kernel_id) to individual KMs by ID"""
    def wrapped(self, kernel_id, *args, **kwargs):
        # get the kernel
        km = self.get_kernel(kernel_id)
        method = getattr(km, f.__name__)
        # call the kernel's method
        r = method(*args, **kwargs)
        # last thing, call anything defined in the actual class method
        # such as logging messages
        f(self, kernel_id, *args, **kwargs)
        # return the method result
        return r
    return wrapped
```

You can see here that it calls the method of the same name on the kernel object before running the body of the function.